# SwingWorker implementation error - abstract method not overridden

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am trying to wrap my brain around swing workers in general, but at the moment I am having difficulty even implementing them. I tried this in a separate class but got an error, but am still getting the error now that I have modeled it after some code I found online. The error I am getting is that it "is abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground() in SwingWorker".

```
    SwingWorker zoomWorker = new SwingWorker() {
    @Override
    public Integer[] doInBackground(int quadrant, boolean zoomed) {

        Integer[] zoomData = new Integer[4];


    return zoomData;
    }


    };
```

Any help would be appreciated - I have read tons of tutorials but get lost in the rhetoric.

Comment: You can't add parameters when overriding method. Correct signature is 'T doInBackground()'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write a concrete class extending `SwingWorker` so that the arguments can be passed in.

Then

Declare the first parameter type for the `SwingWorker` to match the return type of `doInBackground`. Use [`publish`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29) to notify the `EDT` of intermediate and completed results

```
 class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer[], String> {

    private int quadrant;
    private boolean zoomed;

    public MyWorker(int quadrant, boolean zoomed) {
        this.quadrant = quadrant;
        this.zoomed = zoomed;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer[] doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Integer[] zoomData = new Integer[4];

        // use quadrant && zoomData...
        publish("Intermediate data...");
        ...

        publish("complete");
        return zoomData;
    }
};
```

Read: [Why do we need the SwingWorker?](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Comment: I do need the quadrant and zoomed data, though to tell the doInBackground what to do... what would be my method of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Because you cant change the number arguments of an overridden method, you need to either create a concrete type as shown in the update or create custom setters for the anonymous type. The first is cleaner `IMHO`. See update

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground` isn't supposed to take arguments.  Since you aren't even using `quadrant` or `zoomed`, just delete them.